# Android Uploading a file to php

Tags: java, php, android

i want to upload a file to server php using post 
Heres my code

```
    String url = "http://blabla.com/upload.php";
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        "Myfile.log");
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
            new FileInputStream(file), -1);
    reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
    reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    //Do something with response...
}
```

My question  is how can i handle it on php ? If its in `$_FILES` array then what id i should use to put it in uploads folder (`$_FILES['whatShouldBeHere']` )? Thanks .

Comment: Use print_r($_FILES); on PHP and see the response

Comment: @M4HdYaR ok . Thanks i will try